# Navigating multiple files

Tags: multiple-files, load

If I open vim with multiple files on the command line, for example `vim debug.log*` which loads `debug.log`, `debug.log.1` and `debug.log.2`, can I navigate between them, assign them to multiple windows (`:split`/`:vsplit`) or such?

The only shortcut I know for this mode of operation is `:n`, which loads the next file on the list. What more can I do in this multi-file operation mode? (or which help subject covers that?)

Comment: `:previous` (or `:prev`) is the inverse of `:n`, and goes back a file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most relevant help topic is [`:ls`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als), also known as 
[`:files`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Afiles) or 
[`:buffers`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abuffers).

In your `vim debug.log*` example, if you gave the `:ls` command, you would see:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "debug.log"                    line 1
  2      "debug.log.1"                  line 0
  3      "debug.log.2"                  line 0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

… indicating that the first one is the active buffer.

To open `debug.log.2` in the current window, give the [`:b 3`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Ab) or `:b debug.log.2` command to show buffer 3.

To split the window and open buffer 2 in it, give the [`:sb 2`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asb) command.  The vertical-split version of that is [`:vert sb 2`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avertical).

There are many variants of the `:b` command; browse the help topics cited here to get a feel for them.

---

In addition, you can invoke `vim -o debug.log*` to open all of the files, each in its own split, or `vim -O debug.log*` to open them each in a vertical split.

Answer (score 7):

You can also open vim with different parameters.

Opens files in tabs:

```
vim -p debug.log*
```

Opens files in vertical splits:

```
vim -o debug.log*
```

---

There is a cool and quite powerful plugin called CtrlSpace:

https://github.com/szw/vim-ctrlspace

It is very handy if you need to work with many files. Simply you can imagine ctrl-space as own buffer list for every tab. It provides very easy way to navigate between the files, as the author states:

> Vim-CtrlSpace is a Vim plugin to control and organize your working
>   space in Vim. Including managing buffers, files, tabs, sessions, and
>   finally projects. Its approach is somewhat unique, but certainly you
>   will feel at home, especially if you use already split windows, tabs,
>   buffers, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Vi/Vim! Please read our [policy on plugin-recommendation answers](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/99/24) and add some detail about how exactly the plugin addresses the question.

Comment: Related: [How to open multiple files in split mode?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/732/467)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the raw vim functionality mentioned by 200_success, Vim's ecosystem is full of plugins to provide extra functionality, such as:

- [FuzzyFinder](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder) (my plugin of choice)
- [LustyExplorer](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LustyExplorer)
- [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)
- [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T)
- Many others, a bunch of which were mentioned in a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148887/buffer-explorer-for-vim)

However, before you go and start using plugins, it's best to fully understand buffers and windows in vim.

Comment: Please read our [policy on plugin-recommendation answers](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/99/24) and add some detail about how exactly these plugins can benefit the user.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to open a particular file without needing to go through `:ls`, you can use any of the following:

- `:vs filename` opens the file in a vertical split
- `:sp filename` does the same, but in a horizontal split
- `:tabe filename` opens in a new tab

It's worth knowing, too, that if you don't specify a filename, you will open a new split/tab of the current file, which can be handy for long files.

Comment: `:t` is the copy command. For `:tabedit` you need at least `:tabe`.

Comment: Oh dang, you're totally right. Thanks, I'll edit!

Answer (score 2):

There are few useful shortcuts for navigating multiple files:

- `CTRL-^` (where `N` is the buffer number) to jump to the previously edited file.
- `N CTRL-^` (where `N` is the buffer number) to jump to specific buffer.

  For example:

  - <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Control+^</kbd> - go to 1st buffer
  - <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Control+^</kbd> - go to 2nd buffer
  - etc.

  This is equivalent to `:buffer N`.
- Use `:Ex`/`:Sex`/`:Vex` to navigate the current directory.
- Use `:tabs` instead (`vim -p`) with some custom shortcuts in your `.vimrc` such as:

  ```
  " TABS
  " To create a new tab (Control-T)
  nnoremap <C-t> :tabnew<CR>
  inoremap <C-t> <Esc>:tabnew<CR>
  " Tab Navigation (Control+Left <-> Control-Right, Shift+H <-> Shift+L).
  nnoremap <S-h> gT
  nnoremap <S-l> gt
  nnoremap <A-Left> gT
  nnoremap <A-Right> gt
  nnoremap <C-S-Tab> gT
  nnoremap <C-Tab> gt
  " Tab Close (Control-W)
  nnoremap <C-BS> :tabclose<CR>
  inoremap <C-BS> <Esc>:tabclose<CR>
  " Close All (Control-Q)
  nnoremap <C-q> :qa<CR>
  inoremap <C-q> <Esc>:qa<CR>
  ```
- Use `:ba`/`:vert ba` to split, jump into selected buffer via <kbd>Control+w</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd>/<kbd>W</kbd>, then make it the current window (`:on`).